# How to make a circle shaped tab indicator in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, user-interface, dart

I need to have 4 tabs with 4 circles at the bottom indicating which tab you are currently on.
[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So0Ml.png) I cant make it just a Row with 4 containers changing colors, i need them to be fully functional buttons where i can switch between tabs when pressing them. My main problem is that i can't seem to make my tabs narrower, and they end up being about 30 pixels apart, which is not what i want. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code so far

```
Container(
                      width: 22.0.h,
                      child: TabBar(
                        indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(
                            child: Container(
                              height: 1.0.h,
                              width: 1.0.h,
                              decoration:
                                  BoxDecoration(color: UIThemes.buttonDarkBlue, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            child: Container(
                              height: 1.0.h,
                              width: 1.0.h,
                              decoration:
                                  BoxDecoration(color: UIThemes.buttonDarkBlue),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            child: Container(
                              height: 1.0.h,
                              width: 1.0.h,
                              decoration:
                                  BoxDecoration(color: UIThemes.buttonDarkBlue),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            child: Container(
                              height: 1.0.h,
                              width: 1.0.h,
                              decoration:
                                  BoxDecoration(color: UIThemes.buttonDarkBlue),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many packages available for that you can check out these packages which is suitable for your case :

https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_page_indicator

https://pub.dev/packages/dots_indicator

https://pub.dev/packages/page_view_indicators

https://pub.dev/packages/page_indicator

https://pub.dev/packages/ink_page_indicator

https://pub.dev/packages/dot_pagination_swiper

again you can make your custom widget to do that :

You change colour by changing the state of widget.

I think this is may be helpful for you!

Comment: Damn bro, thanks a lot. In my blinding rage because i couldn't figure this one out, i forgot about packages completely.